# In Batch File - Testing if Value is Less than Zero

Tags: powershell, if-statement, batch-file, conditional-statements

I am running a mathmatical formula through a batch file for calculating volume displacement.
I want to run an error check on the result to make sure the value is not negative.
However, the value is always treated as positive when checked. I believe this is a result of batch's limited integers.

I used powershell to do the calculations. The result was put into %result%
I tried to also use powershell to check if %result% was less than or equal to 0, and if it was it would GOTO Error. It only ever resulted in a crash.

Does anyone have any suggestions? Thank you!

```
@echo off
echo.
title RAM Displacement Calculator
:Start
cls

color E0

set /p Bore=Enter RAM Chassis Diameter (Bore): 
echo.
set /p Rod=Enter RAM Rod Diameter (Rod): 
echo.
set /p Extended=Enter Fully Extended Length: 
echo.
set /p Retracted=Enter Fully Retracted Length: 
echo.

color E9
echo | set /p status=Cal

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command %Extended%-%Retracted%') do set A=%%a
echo | set /p status=c
echo | set /p status=u
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command %Bore%*%Bore%') do set B=%%a
echo | set /p status=l
echo | set /p status=a
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command %Rod%*%Rod%') do set C=%%a
echo | set /p status=t
echo | set /p status=i
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command %B%-%C%') do set BC=%%a
echo | set /p status=n
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command %A%*%BC%') do set ABC=%%a
echo | set /p status=g
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command %ABC%*3.14159') do set ABCPi=%%a
echo | set /p status=.
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('powershell -Command %ABCPi%/4') do set result=%%a


if %result% LEQ 0 GOTO Error
if %result% GTR 0 GOTO Result

:Result
echo | set /p status=.  DONE!
echo.
color E2
echo The RAM Displacement Is: %result% Cu In
echo.
@pause
echo.
GOTO Start

:Error
color 4F
echo.
echo ERROR: Invalid Parameters. Displacement must be greater than zero.
@pause
GOTO Start
```

Comment: I'm not really sure why you are doing it this way. Would it not make more sense logically to validate at input, instead of performing the math and then returning an error? The only way your result could be negative, (Less than zero), is if the rod is larger than the bore, or if the retracted length is greater than the extended length. I would advise that you therefore check those things after the second and fourth input respectively, and either re-ask, (goto Start), or goto error at that point.

Comment: The problem doing it your way is, if the end user provided both a larger rod than bore and a larger retracted than extended, two negatives multiplied would result in a postitive and you would not get a math result less than zero. This would mean your code reported a result which was technically impossible, instead or erroring out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right that the issue is that batch can only handle integers; when `LEQ` and `GTR` (and `EQU`, `NEQ`, `LSS`, and `GEQ`) are used, they will only do an integer comparison if the strings being compared contain the digits 0-9 or a `-`. Otherwise, a string comparison is performed. Since `.` is not a digit or a `-`, comparing a decimal results in a string comparison.

You can get around this by using string substitution to remove the decimal point before comparing the numbers.

```
@echo off
echo.
title RAM Displacement Calculator
:Start
cls

color E0

set /p "Bore=Enter RAM Chassis Diameter (Bore): "
echo.
set /p "Rod=Enter RAM Rod Diameter (Rod): "
echo.
set /p "Extended=Enter Fully Extended Length: "
echo.
set /p "Retracted=Enter Fully Retracted Length: "
echo.

color E9
<nul set /p "=Calculating..."

for /f "delims=" %%A in ('powershell -command "((%extended%-%retracted%)*((%bore%*%bore%)-(%rod%*%rod%))*3.14159)/4"') do set "result=%%A"


if %result:.=% LEQ 0 GOTO Error
if %result:.=% GTR 0 GOTO Result

:Result
echo DONE!
echo.
color E2
echo The RAM Displacement Is: %result% Cu In
echo.
pause
echo.
GOTO Start

:Error
color 4F
echo.
echo ERROR: Invalid Parameters. Displacement must be greater than zero.
pause
GOTO Start
```

Note that I also merged all of the calculations into a single powershell command just to make things run faster. The bit that you actually care about is the `%result:.=%`, which replaces all of the `.`s in `%result%` with nothing.

Comment: FYI, you can use a more accurate pi and perform powers also, so your calculation could be changed to `((%Extended% - %Retracted%) * ([Math]::Pow(%Bore%,2) - [Math]::Pow(%Rod%,2)) * [Math]::pi) / 4`

Comment: Thank you! The removal of the decimal worked wonders. I was able to use that method for other error check features I wanted to implement. Thanks again!